# SetTimeout works on executing but causes issue aftewards

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio

I have noticed a slight problem when using setTimeout().

Before I had the code as follows but did not display the SPAN message:

```
 $.each(idsSummary, function () {

  if (finalDate < sampleDate) {

      $('span[data-valmsg-for="newVal[' + Number(iteration) + '].SamplingDate"]').text('Please enter a  correct date.');
    }
  }
```

I put the following with setTimeout() and it showed the message properly:

```
$.each(idsSummary, function () {
      if (finalDate < sampleDate) {
      setTimeout(function () {
      $('span[data-valmsg-for="newVal[' + Number(iteration) + '].SamplingDate"]').text('Please enter a  correct date.');
      })
    }
  }
```

One issue I have noticed in visual studio after I close the program is that I get the following

[image]

I am afraid if I use setTimeOut in Production it may cause issues.

Any way around this in terms of something? I am thinking setTimeout may be slightly costly with these kind of issues.

Comment: I seriously doubt if setTimeout had anything to do with this error!

Comment: I think you forgot the timeout in `setTimeout`?

Comment: XY Problem.  What was wrong with the code without setTimout that caused it to fail?  Your snippet is far from complete to determine the cause.